# Annotation dealloc method never called in ARC, underlying viewcontroller dealloc is called

Tags: ios, dictionary, automatic-ref-counting, mapkit, mkannotation

I learned that I have problem with memory when my app started crashing in my custom annotation method. I was sure managing viewcontroller of the map 100% should have been popped from the view stack.

Here is the code for the annotation, [`TaxiArrivingAnnotation.h`](https://gist.github.com/Zammy/6933590):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import MapKit;

@interface TaxiArrivingAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic) int minutesToTaxiArrival;

-(void) startTimer;
@end
```

and [`TaxiArrivingAnnotation.m`](https://gist.github.com/Zammy/6933546):

```
#import "TaxiArrivingAnnotation.h"

#define SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE 60

@interface TaxiArrivingAnnotation ()
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer * timer;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate * timeOfArrival;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id token1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id token2;
@end

@implementation TaxiArrivingAnnotation

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        __weak TaxiArrivingAnnotation * this = self;

        self.token1 = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
        {
            NSLog(@"DID BECOME ACTIVE");
            NSTimeInterval secondsLeft = [this.timeOfArrival timeIntervalSinceNow];
            if (secondsLeft < 0) {
                self.minutesToTaxiArrival = 0;
                return;
            }

            this.minutesToTaxiArrival = secondsLeft / SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE;

            [this startTimer];
        }];

        self.token2 = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
       {
           NSLog(@"WILL RESIGN ACTIVE");
           [this.timer invalidate];
           this.timer = nil;
       }];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) setMinutesToTaxiArrival:(int)newMinutes {
    self->_minutesToTaxiArrival = newMinutes;
    self->_timeOfArrival = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE * newMinutes];
    if (newMinutes < 0) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}

-(void) startTimer {
    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE target:self selector:@selector(aMinutedPassed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

-(void) aMinutedPassed {
    self.minutesToTaxiArrival--;
}

-(void) dealloc {
   NSLog(@"DEALLOC");
    if (self.timer != nil && [self.timer isValid])
        [self.timer invalidate];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.token1];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.token2];
}
@end
```

I am adding the annotation on `viewDidAppear` and removing it on `viewDidDisappear`. Not only removing it but `nil`-ing the reference. The `dealloc` method still not called when managing viewcontroller `dealloc` is called.

The real problem is that the timer and notifications fire and app crashes because the annotation has been deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to `invalidate` your repeating timer in `dealloc`. The problem is that the timer keeps a strong reference to the `target` (your annotation), which will prevent `dealloc` from ever getting called (because it's only called when there are no more strong references). It's analogous to a strong reference cycle (a.k.a. retain cycle).

You have to `invalidate` the timer when your view controller is deallocated (or whatever the logical event is that initiates the dismissal of the view controller). And since the timer will be invalidated by the time you get to `dealloc`, you can remove the `invalidate` code from the `dealloc` method of the annotation, obviously.

Comment: Then why is my annotation dead when the NSTimer fires? That is what my crash is. Can object be dead without its dealloc method being called?

Comment: @EvgeniPetrov Hard to diagnose crash without stack trace and/or identifying the offending line of code (such as with an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)). I could imagine problems if the annotation is retained after the map associated with it was removed, but I can't say. The crash could be something else. But I know for a fact that trying to `invalidate` a repeating timer in `dealloc` of the `target` will never work. Fix this problem and see if the crash goes away.